# Get the total days for each day in given dates

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, html-table

I am just **looking from some ideas** on how to solve my problem.

I have this working in Excel but I am trying to do it with an html table.

I have a table in a sql server with some dates like the this picture:

[image]

**I am trying to reach this result**. Look at all days between 'starDate' and 'endDate' and sum the total of occurrences for each day:

[image]

Comment: If you have the data in SQL then shouldn't this be a SQL question? Or have you done the calculation and got the results, and just don't understand how to display it in HTML? It's not clear what part of the process you're having a problem with.

Comment: I told my goal. I don' t know how to do it in SQL. Yes, it's better to do it in SQL and then use the result with JQuery.

Comment: why does Dec 25th  have two occurances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the SQL side of things, you can use a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate a "numbers table" that covers the maximum possible difference in days between [startDate] and [endDate], use the DATEADD function to generate a row for every individual date in each range, and then count them up. If your original table was named [tblStartEnd] the query would look something like this:

```sql
WITH numbers (n) AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM numbers WHERE n<100
)
SELECT selectedDate, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, n, startDate) AS selectedDate, endDate 
        FROM tblStartEnd CROSS JOIN numbers
    ) t
WHERE selectedDate <= endDate
GROUP BY selectedDate
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0);
```

producing

```
selectedDate             occurrences
-----------------------  -----------
2017-12-14 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-15 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-16 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-17 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-18 00:00:00.000            2
2017-12-19 00:00:00.000            2
2017-12-20 00:00:00.000            2
2017-12-21 00:00:00.000            2
2017-12-22 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-23 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-24 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-25 00:00:00.000            1
2017-12-26 00:00:00.000            4
2017-12-27 00:00:00.000            4
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000            5
2017-12-29 00:00:00.000            6
```

Then your application code could generate the HTML table from those results.